# Q: MariaDB Installation Problem on Fedora 30

Tags: mysql, mariadb, fedora

I need to install MariaDB and i follow the official Fedora Wiki instructions but i couldn't manage to do a proper installatiın though. So, first i run `dnf install mariadb mariadb-server` command (under root) and the return is

> Package mysql-community-client-8.0.17-1.fc30.x86_64 is already installed.
>   Package mysql-community-server-8.0.17-1.fc30.x86_64 is already installed.
>   Dependencies resolved.
>   Nothing to do.
>   Complete!

So i try to enable/start mariadb with `systemctl start mariadb` and then the return is

> Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found.

I installed other essential packages like php, httpd, mysql etc. and i need to install LAMP too but I get this MariaDB error. Could you show me the way?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because mysql-community packages are configured to obsolete mariadb packages.

The approach below might be not the most optimal, everyone is easy to pitch in to simplify it.

First of all, if you have `mysql-community-*` packages installed, you probably have `MySQL Community` repo configured. Search your `/etc/yum.repo.d` for it and remove it from there:

```
$ grep -ri community /etc/yum.repos.d/*
/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql.repo:[mysql80-community]
/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql.repo:name=MySQL 8.0 Community Server
/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql.repo:baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/$releasever/$basearch/

sudo mv /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql.repo /tmp/
```

Then, check which exactly `mysql-community-*` packages you have:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep mysql-community
mysql-community-server-8.0.17-1.fc30.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-8.0.17-1.fc30.x86_64
mysql-community-client-8.0.17-1.fc30.x86_64
mysql-community-common-8.0.17-1.fc30.x86_64
```

The easiest way to get rid of them is just to remove them by `dnf`. But it needs to be done **very carefully**, because if they have been there for a while, you probably have other packages depending on them. So, when you run the `remove` command, make sure that you **don't** have an auto-yes (`-y` option), and examine the output before agreeing to uninstall. It might look somewhat like this:

```
$ sudo dnf remove mysql-community*
Dependencies resolved.
===================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                           Architecture                      Version                                   Repository                                     Size
===================================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 mysql-community-client                            x86_64                            8.0.17-1.fc30                             @mysql80-community                             66 M
 mysql-community-common                            x86_64                            8.0.17-1.fc30                             @mysql80-community                            8.3 M
 mysql-community-libs                              x86_64                            8.0.17-1.fc30                             @mysql80-community                            7.5 M
 mysql-community-server                            x86_64                            8.0.17-1.fc30                             @mysql80-community                            128 M
Removing dependent packages:
 perl-DBD-MySQL                                    x86_64                            4.050-2.fc30                              @fedora                                       367 k
Removing unused dependencies:
```

Note the section `Removing dependent packages`. I added only one package to make an example, but in your case it can be much longer and scarier. If you do have the section and don't know if you can safely remove all its contents, it maybe be better not to do it (just yet). Abort the operation.

```
Is this ok [y/N]: n
Operation aborted.
```

Instead, you can try to **replace** mysql-community packages with MariaDB. There is `dnf` option `--allowerasing` which seems to do the trick, but you need to specify package names with versions to work around mysql obsoleting (replace the version in the command with the actual version available by the time you are doing it):

```
$ sudo dnf install --allowerasing --setopt=install_weak_deps=False mariadb-server-10.3.17 mariadb-10.3.17
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:18 ago on Mon 07 Oct 2019 02:25:32 PM UTC.
Dependencies resolved.
===================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                             Architecture                    Version                                     Repository                                   Size
===================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mariadb                                             x86_64                          3:10.3.17-1.fc30                            updates                                     5.9 M
 mariadb-server                                      x86_64                          3:10.3.17-1.fc30                            updates                                      17 M
Installing dependencies:
 mariadb-common                                      x86_64                          3:10.3.17-1.fc30                            updates                                      36 k
 mariadb-connector-c-config                          noarch                          3.1.3-1.fc30                                updates                                      12 k
 mariadb-errmsg                                      x86_64                          3:10.3.17-1.fc30                            updates                                     205 k
 mysql-selinux                                       noarch                          1.0.0-8.fc30                                fedora                                       35 k
 psmisc                                              x86_64                          23.1-5.1.fc30                               fedora                                      133 k
Removing dependent packages:
 mysql-community-client                              x86_64                          8.0.17-1.fc30                               @mysql80-community                           66 M
 mysql-community-server                              x86_64                          8.0.17-1.fc30                               @mysql80-community                          128 M

Transaction Summary
```

Now nothing is removed as dependencies, apart from mysql-community, which was the goal.

*The option `--setopt=install_weak_deps=False` is not strictly necessary, but without it `dnf` installs many packages which you probably don't need. You can run without the option to see the difference.*

After you have replaced the server and client packages, you can check what else you have left from MySQL community server, and try to remove remaining packages if you want:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep mysql-community
mysql-community-libs-8.0.17-1.fc30.x86_64
mysql-community-common-8.0.17-1.fc30.x86_64

$ sudo dnf remove mysql-community-libs mysql-community-common
Dependencies resolved.
===================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                           Architecture                      Version                                   Repository                                     Size
===================================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 mysql-community-common                            x86_64                            8.0.17-1.fc30                             @mysql80-community                            8.3 M
 mysql-community-libs                              x86_64                            8.0.17-1.fc30                             @mysql80-community                            7.5 M

Transaction Summary
```

Now it seems safe, no dependencies anymore.

---

There is one catch I can think of. **If you don't know why mysql-community was installed** in the first place, it's possible that you have something which requires exactly it, and won't be satisfied with MariaDB replacing it. Then it probably won't allow you to replace the packages. But I can't guess what it could be, so it's up to you to try and see. I suppose it will show up in `dnf` output which you examine before confirmation.